# C++ how to close the cmd exe after opening an excel file through system command from the same MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

system( "file path" )  helped me to open a excel application, but then, I lost control from the MFC exe as the cmd.exe holds the control ( with the excel openend). Can anyone please help me in closing the cmd exe alone, and getting the control back to my MFC application. I would also want the openend excel to stay, displayed

Comment: you can try system("start excel \"file path\"");

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening the cmd.exe and launching the excel application along with the file path, you can use the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to does it easier.

Here is the example:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"excel", L"your_file_path", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a commendt, you can use `system("start excel \"file path\")` that doesn't let the command interpreter to wait for excel to return.

But you can better not use `system`, and refer to a more congruent process control API, like [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to call excel directly from your app.

This will prevent some malware to place an excel.cmd file in you path to do what he wants with your application.